# Doom 3 Wily Werewolf - need help getting it running

Tags: games, 15.10

I have the Doom 3 game on CDs, I have followed the guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Doom3. As the /usr/local folder doesn't seem to let me put the pak files in I have moved the installation (it seemed to install fine via the terminal) to home/downloads. 
So I'm at the stage where I've installed it as per the Ubuntu docs, copied the pak files in to the base folder from the original CDs and moved it to the downloads folder.
Now what? I can't work out what to do next. I suspect I am very close to getting it running but I can't work out what to do. Just moved to Ubuntu and loving it, any help would be appreciated :)

Update: I was a fool, I installed the wrong file - the SDK. I've now installed the right one, Doom 3 starts - but no sound at all. I have tried the various fixes mentioned online but nothing works. Basically no sound at all. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

> ***sudo*** cp /media/cdrom0/Setup/Data/base/pak00*.pk4 /usr/local/games/doom3/base

You just had to use sudo, then it would proceed fine. There still may be hardlinked files in the installation, although I hope, that it will run.

As of running the game. Try to find executable, it should be file named `doom3`, so just run `find . -name "doom3"` in your home folder to find it and then enter `./path-to-binary/doom3` command to run it

EDIT:

Have you even run the installation script of Linux binary? There are no exes in Linux, I think that in OS X it is similar...

The best way for you now would be to go through the tutorial once again word by word. The only catch for you may be that the tutorial presumes copying `*.pk4` files from mounted CD. So you have to change source folder in this case...

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go on Sunday. Presumably as I have saved the pak files in a different location I can use the same command to copy them to the right folder? They are currently in my home/downloads folder. I also can't find the exe anywhere. If you had any further guidance it would be useful - sorry for being such a newbie, I made the switch to Ubuntu on Thursday from Mac OS X and have a lot to learn

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Thanks, yes I have run the installation script. When I first did it I was ultra tired, I cold have easily missed something. I'll have a look back this afternoon. Thanks for the advice